# No "Compare & pull request" button / pushing from wrong user

Tags: git, github, push

I've pushed a branch to Github using `git push origin new_branch`. When I visit Github in browser I see the new branch and a button to "Compare" but no option to open a pull request.

As I've looked into this I believe the problem is that I was improperly credentialed when I pushed. When I run `git log` I see that the author of my most recent push is my local username and not tied to Github

⟶ 1. How do I make sure I am pushing my branch as my GitHub self?

⟶ 2. Will I be able to re-push the branch after #1?

Comment: For 1): You can set your email address using `git config` and then re-commit with `git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author`. For 2): You will need to force push because the commit hash is going to change. Github ties the commit authorship to your account using the email address. If you have multiple commits, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/10875738).

Answer (score 1):

The author on a commit has nothing to do with authentication to a remote service like GitHub.

If you can push to a repository, that means you own it, or you are declared as collaborator.

[To create a PR](http://checkouts%20both%20the%20containing%20and%20the%20sub%20module.), you need to switch to the branch you want to create a PR for.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The button didn't show up at all. Had to ctrl+click inside the terminal with the git's clue:

> remote: Create a pull request for 'updatereadme' on GitHub by visiting:
> remote:      https://github.com/UserName/your_repo/pull/new/your_branch